# Reading from InputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I need to write application which will be reeding data from InputStream. In short: my app will firstly connect to Bluetooth device. After connection my app will be reeding data From InputStream continuously. I mean that the device will send data for 20 milisec and app will be receive this data working for 24 hour maybe even more. For now I read this data in that way:

```
while((bytesReceived = is.read(buffer))>-1) {
  //things to do with data
}
```

This loop receive data when it is in stream and stops when inputstream is close. My problem is that I think it is not optimal solution. After is.read(buffer) receive data it blocks waiting for next data what consume a lot of processor. Do you know any better way to read data what consume least processor power. Thanks for any help.

BTW. I write my app in Java on Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A blocking `read` does not consume CPU. The OS will put the calling thread/process to sleep.

That loop is fine.